# How can I get a unique id for a List<T>

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier, generic-list

I have a `List<T>`, where `T` is a class that has an `int` field for an `id`. How is the best way to get a unique `id` value that has not been used in any of the objects in the `List<T>`?

How is this procedure normally coded? Is there a data type that can help with this or do I need to store the largest id value?

**EDIT**

How about when I get an id for an object that is 1. I then delete the object from the List. When I create a new object, I would like the unique id to be 2. In this situation, is there any better way than to store the last unique id?

Thanks.

Comment: Step one would be to say what language you are using.

Comment: use the hashcode of the class `T` for an identifier

Comment: Or you just could create a GUID for the Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that approach I'd write an inherited class of List<T> which holds the logic, so you wouldn't need to implement it everywhere you access the list.
You can even leave it generic if you have a minimum interface which has the Id value.

```
interface IWithId {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class CustomList<T> : List<T> where T : class, IWithId {
    private lastUsedId = 1;

    public void AddObjectWithAutomaticId(T newObject) {
        newObject.Id = lastUsedId++;
        base.Add(newObject);
    }

    public T GetElementById(int id) {
         return base.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    }
}
```

The `Remove` method would still work as before. The class stores the last used Id, independent what you remove. The `Add` method is also still available, when you want to add an object with a given Id and not auto-fill it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that a GUID would suit you as an id property. If, however, you need to use an int then I suggest a new class.

The problem with inheriting `List<T>` is that you would have to override multiple methods to ensure that things such as `Add()`, `AddRange()`, `Insert()` can't add duplicate ids and update the stored maximum id. It would be easy to miss one.

I would use a class which doesn't inherit anything, but uses a dictionary internally. This won't have all the same methods as a `List<T>`, but that's not necessarily a bad thing - it saves mistakes being made and you can have a `ToList()` method for when they want to query it as if it was a `List<T>`.

Using part of a previous answer to ensure that `T` has an `Id` property gives:

```
interface IHasId {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class AutoIdList<T> where T : class, IHasId {
    private readonly IDictionary<int, T> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    //Using this list ensures you don't duplicate ids even
    //for an item added with an explicit id then removed
    private IList<int> _historicalIds = new List<int>();
    private int highestAutoGeneratedId = 0;

    public List<T> ToList() {
        return _dictionary.Values.ToList();
    }

    public void Add(T item, bool generateId) {
        if (generateId) {
            highestAutoGeneratedId = NextId();
            T.Id = highestAutoGeneratedId;
        }
        Add(T);
    }

    public void Replace(T item) {
        _dictionary[item.Id] = item;
    }

    public void Remove(T item) {
        _dictionary.Remove(item.Id);
    }

    private void Add(T item) {
        if (_historicalIds.Contains(T.Id)) {
            //throw an appropriate exception
        } else {
            _historicalIds.Add(T.Id);
            _dictionary.Add(T.Id, T);
        }
    }

    private int NextId() {
        var id = highestAutoGeneratedId + 1;
        while (_historicalIds.Contains(id)) {
            id++;
        }
        return id;
    }

    //More methods to simulate AddRange, Insert, etc if required. Leave if not.
    //Should all have simple logic but require checking of Id if adding anything
    //Also need logic to maintain the list of used ids
}
```